# How to bind Endpoint to RoutingKey while using ConfigureConsumer in MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm playing around with MassTransit on top of RabbitMQ to replace EasyNetQ in one of our current projects.

I basically set up a Consumer which worked great - however I am wondering how to specify the routingKey of the generated Queue while using the function 'ConfigureConsumer' like:

```cs
x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), hostConfigurator =>
                    {
                        hostConfigurator.Username("guest");
                        hostConfigurator.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "submit-order", ep =>
                    {
                        ep.ConfigureConsumer<CreatePersonConsumer>(provider);
                    });
                }));
```

The above sample is not setting any RoutingKey.
According to the Documentation the only Option I found to specify a routingKey is using the 'Bind' method to bind to an Exchange manually like so:

```cs
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "priority-orders", x =>
    {
        x.BindMessageExchanges = false;

        x.Consumer<CreatePersonConsumer>();

        x.Bind("submitorder", s => 
        {
            s.RoutingKey = "KEY";
            s.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
        });
    });
```

This approach bother me a little due to the need of specifying the exchange name by using a string literal...

Did I miss any option to only specify the routingKey without the need of Setting the exchange Name directly as a string?

Answer (score 2):

I just created a sample that shows how to use direct exchanges and routing keys with MassTransit.

https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct

The key is two configurations, which should be prior to any receive endpoint configuration.

```
configurator.Message<ContentReceived>(c => c.SetEntityName("content.received"));

configurator.Publish<ContentReceived>(c => { c.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct; });
```