# MassTransit change exchange type problems in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit

I want to use direct exchange-type in Masstransit. I am using ASP.NET Core Web API.

In startup.cs, I have this code:

```
services.AddMassTransit(config => {
            config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
                cfg.Host("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672");
                cfg.Publish<Order>(m =>
                {
                    m.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                    m.BindAlternateExchangeQueue("unmatched");
                });
            });
        });
```

In `Controller.cs`, I have this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Order order)
{
    await ibus.Publish(order, x => x.SetRoutingKey("B"));
    return Ok();
}
```

When I do my tests, it throws exception, and I can see the exchange-type value in rabbitmq fanout.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Delete the existing exchange, re-run the tests.

Comment: Hi @user2814851, you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418439/11398810) to configure in the startup.cs.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to make my Web API run after using the sample code in the above link. But have to keep all of the libs versions without changing.